# output_safety.rb:34 warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

When starting up my WEBrick server, I get next warning when calling the home page:

```
c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-
  3.2.2.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:34 
  warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this warning?

+

I'm running JRuby in 1.9 mode, but here I'm getting an error from a gem in 1.8 folder. Why is that? Shouldn't the gems from the 1.9 folder be used?

Comment: Having this on stock MRI Ruby 1.9.2 and .3 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue is discussed here [github.com/rails/rails/issues/3927](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3927)